# I am trying to cancel factorials in Java

Tags: java, counting

I'm trying to calculate the number of rCombinations for a project for school and I can't seem to get my method to return the correct values.

I talked to my professor and he recommended canceling the common factors in factorials. Such that

```
35!/32! = 35*34*33.
```

This is what I have so far.

```
public static long rCombinations(int n, int r) {

   int q = n-r;
   long x = 1;
   for(int i = r; i <= r; i ++)
   {
       x = n*(n-i);
   }
   return x/factorial(r);
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to manipulate them symbolically, because factorials blow through the representable range of integers *fast*.

Comment: This for loop will loop only once no matter what was the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n!/m!, where n >= m

```
int out = 1;
for(int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    out *= i;
```

For n!/m!, where n <= m

```
double out = 1;
for(int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    out /= i;
```

In both cases, out = n!/m!

Note that it's still easy to overflow an int, 55!/49! is too big

Comment: I figured it out but now my longs are overflowing and we were told we don't need the BigInteger class. I should be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use this implementation for calculating large factorial of numbers without BigInteger as follows :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class N_Faktorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int u = 1, A[] = new int[9999999];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("n=");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    A[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            A[j] *= i;
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (A[j] > 9) {
                A[j + 1] += A[j] / 10;
                A[j] %= 10;
            }

            if (A[u + 1] != 0) {
                u++;
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = u; i >= 1; i--) {

        System.out.print(A[i]);

    }
    //when  n>=24  count of digit of n! is equal to n+1.
    System.out.println("\n Result : " + n + " count of digit " + u);

}
```

}

After this you need some solution for doing division operation.
Hope it helps!.